# So how do i know which marker clicked?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to open a new Activity about which clicked Marker. But i can't. Because markers are adding automatically and i am getting coordinate from the database.

How do I know which marker clicked??

```
for(int i=0; i<all.size();i=i+4){    
    // her kaydin id,lat,lng,title bilgisi alinip ArrayListe atiliyor..

    Double latDouble = Double.parseDouble(all.get(i+1));  
    Double lngDouble = Double.parseDouble(all.get(i+2));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latDouble, lngDouble)).snippet(all.get(i).toString()).title(all.get(i+3)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [OnMarkerClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html), but if you don't want a listener in each marker and the info is in the marker, you can use [OnInfoWindowClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener.html) like this:

```
getMap().setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        // here you have the Marker to start the activity, for example:
        String url = marker.getTitle();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "ID" to each marker added.

Then, implement OnMarkerClickListener. As given in documentaion:

> "You can use an OnMarkerClickListener to listen for click events on
>   the marker. To set this listener on the map, call
>   GoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(OnMarkerClickListener). When a user
>   clicks on a marker, onMarkerClick(Marker) will be called and the
>   marker will be passed through as an argument."

You will receive a "Marker" object in OnMarkerClickListener. Compare the "ID"s .

Comment: yes but automatically given id names are: m0,m1,m2.. etc. i don't know which is which

Comment: final Marker addMarker(MarkerOptions options)
 Returns Marker object. You will need to maintain Marker Ids.

Answer (score 0):

If you know order of your data, you can get the order of marker and match them.
I mean, your first line of database represents  the marker which id is = 0. 
You can get Id of a marker like this.

```
    int order = Integer.parseInt(marker.getId().substring(1));

googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            int order = Integer.parseInt(marker.getId().substring(1));
        }
    });
```